# Check if package is Unix or Linux

Tags: linux, software-installation, solaris

I have a tar archive containing files necessary for the installation of a piece of enterprise software. I want to install this software on a Solaris machine, however I don't know whether the package is for Linux or Unix. There is a setup.bin file which is supposed to be the entry point for the setup process.

Is there some way I can perhaps read this bin file and find out if it is a Linux or Unix executable? I'm unsure how to find out if I have the right package.

Comment: Is there no documentation? Readme or similar?

Comment: Tried to run 'readelf' or 'objdump' or 'file' on this entry file? Should give u useful info. These are linux shell commands.

Comment: @Tomasz there is but it doesn't explicitly say which OS it's for. However I've just recalled something more important. This is a SPARC machine, so that might make it easier to determine if it's the right package.

Comment: Also: try to run ldd <nameOfFile> -> if it's unix you'll see the libs it requires.